# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent Relationship 1-1 Query

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.3, one-to-one

Hi guys how could I query a data from my database with one-to-one relationship on eloquent model?

I want to query the menus with specific category id.

For example I only want to query the meals with "Breakfast Category".

Menu Model:

```
 public function menucat()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\MenuCat', 'menu_cat_id', 'id');
  }
```

Menu_Cat Model

```
 public function menus()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Menu', 'menu_cat_id', 'menu_cat_id');
  }
```

Database Table:

menus Table

```
id | menu_cat_id | menuName
```

menu_cat Table

```
menu_cat_id | menuCatName
```

I find it easy using the Query builder but I would like to use the eloquent to query out the data I need.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

in the documentation you have that

return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

you need to inverse menu_cat_id and id like that

return $this->hasOne('App\MenuCat', 'id', 'menu_cat_id');

Comment: Appreciate it! But how can I query out the menu with the specific category only?

Comment: you can add the where method at the end of the query like
$this->hasOne('App\MenuCat', 'id', 'menu_cat_id')->where('category', 1);

Comment: Thanks man! How about if I want to do it as an && condition. Query out menu for category one where date is today?

Comment: $menucat = Menu::where('menu_cat_id', 1)
              ->where('menuDate', $date)
              ->get();